# nginx error - "proxy_cache_path" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx

I am getting the following error with my nginx.conf in sites-enabled when i try starting nginx on CentOs 7.5.

> [root@centos-linux sites-enabled]# nginx -s reload nginx: [emerg]
>   "proxy_cache_path" directive is not allowed here in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ckan_default:1

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:30m max_size=250m;
proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx_proxy 1 2;

server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_auth_tkt;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_auth_tkt;
        proxy_cache_valid 30m;
        proxy_cache_key $host$scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;
        # In emergency comment out line to force caching
        # proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    }

}
```

Not sure what its complaining about as this works on an ubuntu setup.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Something must be different from the Ubuntu setup, `proxy_cache_path` is only allowed in the `http` context on any platform. You config as shown is incomplete. Can you share more of the configuration?

Answer (score 10):

I solved it, looks like i had to encapsulate the entire template in http {} as so:

```
http {
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:30m max_size=250m;
proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx_proxy 1 2;

server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_auth_tkt;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_auth_tkt;
        proxy_cache_valid 30m;
        proxy_cache_key $host$scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;
        # In emergency comment out line to force caching
        # proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: I get this error - `nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1`